# Nodemailer error with no explanation

Tags: jquery, gmail, response, nodemailer

I have a nodemailer functionality on my webpage, which I'm trying to test locally.
In my package.json the version is `"nodemailer": "0.7.1"`.
In my routing file I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home');
});

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
  service: "Gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "example@gmail.com",
    pass: "examplePass"
  }
});

router.get('/send',function(req,res){
    var mailOptions={
       from : req.query.from
    }
      console.log(mailOptions);
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
    if (error){
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
      res.end("sent");
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And in my page I have a script at the bottom which goes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var to,from;
  $(".signup").on("click", function(){
    from = $("#search").val();

    $.get("/send",
          {from:from},
          function(data){
          alert("Thanks :) We'll keep you updated.");
          location.reload(true);
          });
    });
});
```

I tested some things and when I click the signup button I do get the 'from' field, as well as the alert message, and the page reloads after I approve the alert.

The problem is that the mail doesn't actually arrive to the inbox, and the console msg (firefox) reads simply `"syntax error     send:1:1"`

If I look into the network of the request, I can see that the status code is 200 OK, but the 'response' tab only says "error", without any explanation.

I can't debug this with no information so I hope someone will have an idea why it isn't working. It should work by the way, because I have another site where it works perfectly and and basically did copy-paste from there...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was in the data fields from the Nodemailer STMP function. Specifically I just left out the 'to : email@gmail.com' parameter.

I was able to debug this issue through the console.log on the server side and eventually bumping into this post which gave me the idea to check the function fields again: [Sending email from local host with Nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264946/sending-email-from-local-host-with-nodemailer)

In any case, adding the 'to:' in addition to the 'from:' did the trick.